# AWS second NIC vs secondary IP

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

this is just a fundamental question.

I started working on Amazon Web Services last night and realised that I can either add a second NIC to my instance or add a secondary IP to my existing NIC.

**Questions:**

1. What advantages/disadvantages have each configuration?
2. When I assign a new NIC to my instance, am I really adding a hardware NIC or a Virtual one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit.  You would just have the ability to have 4 private IPS, or connect to multiple VPCs.  Also some applications may require separate NICs, but you don't ever really see that anymore.